# numpy indexing unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, numpy

I have an ndarray `bla` with shape (6,4). When I print it, I get:

```
    [[0. 1. 1. 1.]
     [0. 0. 0. 2.]
     [0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

All very normal.

However, when I try and get an element from it `bla[0][0]` I get `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`

I can get the first row with `bla[0]`, which returns `[0. 1. 1. 1.]` (as expected). However, I cannot get the first column like `bla[:,0]` - this returns `IndexError: too many indices for array`

I assumed I have made some kind of user error but after checking and rechecking, I can't fathom what the problem may be. Executing `np.zeros((6,4))[0][0]` works as expected.

**UPDATE1**

Another strange phenomenon: `np.zeros((6,4))==np.zeros(bla.shape)` gives True, yet `np.zeros(bla.shape)[0][0]` gives error, while `np.zeros((6,4))[0][0]` works fine (directly from output: `bla.shape:  (6, 4)`)

```
    repr(bla):
    array([[0., 1., 1., 1.],
    [0., 0., 0., 2.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

**UPDATE2**
pickle.dumps(bla) gives this:

```
b'\x80\x03cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x00cnumpy\nndarray\nq\x01K\x00\x85q\x02C\x01bq\x03\x87q\x04Rq\x05(K\x01K\x06K\x04\x86q\x06cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x07X\x02\x00\x00\x00f8q\x08K\x00K\x01\x87q\tRq\n(K\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00<q\x0bNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq\x0cb\x89C\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q\rtq\x0eb.'
```

Comment: What is the `type` of `bla`, and `bla[0]`? Can you add the outcome of `type(bla)` and `type(bla[0])`?

Comment: Hard to tell what's the issue without code to reproduce it. Not sure if that's what is happening, but it is possible to pack a NumPy array into a NumPy `object` scalar in a confusing way like that. See if `bla.item()[:, 0]` works.

Comment: Cannot reproduce

Comment: type(bla) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> type(bla[0]) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: @jdehesa `bla.item()` gives `ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar`

Comment: Try to give some more details... What is `bla.shape`? `bla.dtype`? Does the problem persist if you do `bla2 = np.array(bla)` (and try the same on `bla2`)?

Comment: That's super weird. Okay, time for big guns, just so we can try to reproduce it, since all of us are just guessing blindly: can you paste in the results of `import pickle; pickle.dumps(bla)`?

Comment: @Amadan so I don't know how to interpret this but i've pasted it in the question :)

Comment: sorry it was auto-truncated for some reason, updated now

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Let's see if you get the same thing: `pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(bla))[0][0]`? In any case, something seems to be seriously weird on your end. :P EDIT: Also, where does `bla` come from? How is it created?

Comment: Confirmed can't reproduce with the `pickle.dumps` output. .  `bla[0][0]` returns `0.0` for me

Comment: Your issue does not seem to be reproducible anyhow. It might be something wrong with you NumPy installation, your Python session or something else. See if the problem persists if you open another Python session and load that object (`import pickle; import numpy as np; bla = pickle.loads(<pickle dump string that you posted>)`). Try reinstalling/updating NumPy.

Comment: ok thank you all for your help :) I'll look into my configurations. @jdehesa running that code in a separate python shell works just fine, interestingly enough. perhaps has to do with pytest, during which the problem commenced?